# How to calculate difference of condition close and current close for all occurences of the condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
con = ta.barssince(ta.rsi(close, 14) > 20) == 1

var flag = false

if ta.barssince(ta.ema(close, 50) > ta.ema(close, 200)) == 1
    flag := true

if ta.barssince(ta.ema(close, 50) < ta.ema(close, 200)) == 1
    flag := false

var labels = array.new_label()
var conCloses = array.new_float()

if con
    array.unshift(labels, label.new(bar_index, close, ""))
    array.unshift(conClose, close)

if flag[1]
    var txt = 0.
    for conClose in conCloses
        txt := close - conClose

    for label in labels
        label.set_text(label, str.tostring(txt))

afterFlag = flag[1] and not flag

if afterFlag
    array.clear(labels)
    array.clear(conCloses)
```

I want to calculate the difference of the close of when the condition is met with the current close for all the occurence of the condition, and display it with a label. I tried using the same logic with the previous question I asked but only find myself struggling. Help would be appreciated.

*Inserted a pic of what I'm trying to achieve.*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the values to be updated on every tick you should set the label's text in the global scope, otherwise, the text will be updated only on the `flag[1]` occurrence and real-time price would be ignored.

The second `for..in` structure with labels in your script is using only the last value of the `txt` as it is executed after all iterations of the previous  loop. You can use indexing in the `for [index, element]..in` structure to set the label's text:

```
//@version=5
indicator("myScript", overlay = true)

con = ta.barssince(ta.rsi(close, 14) > 20) == 1

var flag = false

if ta.barssince(ta.ema(close, 50) > ta.ema(close, 200)) == 1
    flag := true

if ta.barssince(ta.ema(close, 50) < ta.ema(close, 200)) == 1
    flag := false

var labels = array.new_label()
var conCloses = array.new_float()

if con
    array.unshift(labels, label.new(bar_index, close, "", color = color.new(color.blue, 80), style = label.style_label_up))
    array.unshift(conCloses, close)

var txt = 0.
for [i, conClose] in conCloses
    txt := conClose - close
    label.set_text(array.get(labels, i), str.tostring(txt))
```